# Why does the browser not send cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I set a cookie from JavaScript like this:

```
document.cookie =
    't=sometokengoeshere; max-age=3600; domain=localhost; samesite=strict';
```

Afterwards, the cookie is really there:

```
console.log(document.cookie); // outputs correct cookie
```

If my JavaScript is served from localhost:3000 and tries to contact my backend running on localhost:80, the browser *does* send the cookie along with subsequent requests. Which is odd, because I thought this should be considered cross-origin.

If, however, my JavaScript as well as the backend are both served from localhost:80, the browser does *not* send the cookie along with subsequent requests. There is no error message in the console.

The 'subsequent requests' I mentioned are requests made by the browser after I set the url of a HTMLAudioElement like this:

```
audio.src = 'http://localhost/audio.php';
```

Of course, I do the above line *after* I have set the cookie.

I can reproduce this odd behaviour in both Firefox and Chrome. What's going on here? I also tried dropping the `domain` or `samesite` from the cookie, or use `samesite=lax`, doesn't work either.

Comment: So you are not talking about normal requests here, but specifically those made by JavaScript? Then you should show us the details of those.

Comment: I've updated the question. They are requests by the browser as a response to me setting the url of a HTMLAudioElement.

Comment: What’s the CORS mode of that audio element? What happens when you just visit http://localhost/audio.php directly in a new browser tab, does it send the cookie with that request then?

Comment: No, in a new tab I also see my cookie not set.

Comment: audio.crossOrigin is null in both cases (JS running from localhost:80 or running from localhost:3000)

Comment: Aha, setting audio.crossOrigin to 'use-credentials' helped. The cookie is now sent in both cases. I still don't know why it worked when JS was running from :3000, but never mind. Thanks you all.